# Need to keep textbox and menubar on main frame visible when I open up other panels, then reopen main frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a main JFrame with a menubar, jPanel with info, and a textbox in the main frame.  I am trying to open up other panels, but have the main menubar appear plus the textbox from the main frame remain with the new panel showing as well.  When I open a new panel, I get the menubar, but not the textbox that was on the main frame.  Plus when I try to reopen the main frame by closing the new panel, I only get the menubar, main jpanel within the main frame, but not the textbox.  Here is my code.  I am not sure why I do not get the textboxes below the main frame's main panel to show up again.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
private void MenuItem_caseOpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    caseNewPanel = new CaseNewPanel();
    this.setContentPane(caseNewPanel);
    this.setTitle("Case Menu");
    this.setSize(1200,800);
    this.setBounds(5, 5, 1200, 800);
    this.invalidate(); this.validate();
    this.repaint();      
}                                                  

private void jButton_exitMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    System.exit(0);   
}                                         

private void jMenuItem_caseCloseActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    
    this.getContentPane().removeAll();
    mainMenuFrame = new MainMenuFrame();
    this.setContentPane(mainMenuFrame.jPanel_mainMenu);
    mainMenuFrame.jPanel_mainMenu.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(567,304);
    this.setBounds(300, 300, 567,304);
    this.invalidate(); this.validate();
    this.repaint();        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I open a new panel, I get the menubar, but not the textbox that was on the main frame

Correct. A Swing component can only have a single parent.

For this problem you should be using a panel with a CardLayout to enable easy switching of panels.

So you need to either:

1. swap the complete panel, which means you need to create a separate text field for each panel.
2. swap a portion of each panel, which means the text field is common and only the bottom part of the panel is swapped.

Option 1 should be self explanatory.

For option 2, check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). In this example the JComboBox is the common component (not a JTextField), but the concept is the same.

Comment: Thank you;  I will take a look at that and try it out.